# Rails how to update a column after saving?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to create an after_save method for my rate action. It would divide rating_score/ratings and update the column rating.

```
class KonkurrancersController < ApplicationController
  def rate
    @konkurrancer = Konkurrancer.find(params[:id])
    @container = "Konkurrancer"+@konkurrancer.id.to_s

    @konkurrancer.rating_score += params[:vind][:rating].to_i
    @konkurrancer.ratings += 1
    @konkurrancer.save

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

This is my model:

```
class Konkurrancer < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :do_foobar

  private
    def do_foobar

      rating_score = self.rating_score
      ratings = self.ratings
      rating = (rating_score/ratings)
      self.update_attributes(:rating => rating)

    end
end
```

My rails log:

```
Started POST "/konkurrancers/rate/46" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-04-26 23:40:56 +0200

  Processing by KonkurrancersController#rate as */*
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"Ô£ô", "authenticity_token"=>"MACFM37hX4S6XA9vryn7gtfl21P
vcaPBSiKDI8mfurg=", "vind"=>{"rating"=>"4"}, "id"=>"46"}
  ←[1m←[36mKonkurrancer Load (1.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT `konkurrancers`.* FROM `kon
kurrancers`←[0m
  ←[1m←[35mCACHE (0.0ms)←[0m  SELECT `konkurrancers`.* FROM `konkurrancers`
  ←[1m←[36mCACHE (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT `konkurrancers`.* FROM `konkurrancers`←
[0m
  ←[1m←[35mKonkurrancer Load (1.0ms)←[0m  SELECT `konkurrancers`.* FROM `konkurr
ancers` WHERE (`konkurrancers`.`cached_slug` = '46') LIMIT 1
  ←[1m←[36mSQL (2.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT sluggable_id FROM slugs WHERE ((slugs.slu
ggable_type = 'Konkurrancer' AND slugs.name = '46' AND slugs.sequence = 1))←[0m
  ←[1m←[35mKonkurrancer Load (1.0ms)←[0m  SELECT `konkurrancers`.* FROM `konkurr
ancers` WHERE (`konkurrancers`.`id` = 46) LIMIT 1
  ←[1m←[36mSQL (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mBEGIN←[0m
  ←[1m←[35mLink Load (1.0ms)←[0m  SELECT `links`.* FROM `links` WHERE (`links`.k
onkurrancer_id = 46) LIMIT 1
  ←[1m←[36mSQL (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mROLLBACK←[0m
Rendered konkurrancers/_rating.html.erb (1.0ms)
Rendered konkurrancers/rate.js.erb (22.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 606ms (Views: 286.0ms | ActiveRecord: 6.0ms)
```

How should I create this?

Comment: see this [callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

what you want is a callback. You can create an after_save callback on your Konkurrancer model, which triggers after the **save()** method is called for that model.

For example:

```
class Konkurrancer < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :do_foobar

  private
    def do_foobar

      rating_score = self.rating_score
      ratings = self.ratings
      rating = (rating_score/ratings)
      self.update_attributes(:ratings => rating)

    end
end
```

**[EDIT]** You should use **self**, since the model you are editing is the model itself. Test it out, and apply necessary logic/implementation.

Have a look at this [guide](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) for more info.

Hope that helps!

Comment: How do I make sure that is the right column that gets updated?

Comment: I updated my answer, with an example code block that supposedly highlights your issue. Modify it to your needs.

Comment: I am not getting any value saved in my rating column

Comment: Try self.update_attributes!(:ratings => 'foobar') should work. A callback was what you are looking for. I can't debug your code, you are going to have to do some trial and error

Comment: @tzown: your names are confusing (rating and ratings), @Christian has a typo in his last line: it should be `self.update_attributes :rating => rating` and then it should work just fine.

Comment: Still the column rating dont gets any value. I have updated my question with my rails log

Comment: But isn't this a way to fall into infinite loop, because update_attributes will call model.save again making the callback firing again?

Comment: Yes Nozim, this will go into an endless recursion and will never actually work. The correct way to do this is to use `self.update_column` as per Zakelfassi's answer.

Comment: This solution does not work. You have to use update_column as per Zakelfassi's answer.

Answer (score 80):

Any `update_attribute` in an `after_save` callback will cause recursion, in Rails3+.
What should be done is:

```
after_save :updater
# Awesome Ruby code
# ...
# ...

private

  def updater
    self.update_column(:column_name, new_value) # This will skip validation gracefully.
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Many of the answers on this post might have been correct but are out of date now. The [Rails docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#available-callbacks) suggests assigning values directly (`self.attribute = 'value'`) instead of updating or saving attributes (`update(attribute: 'value'`) in callbacks.

#### Good

```rb
after_save :do_foobar

private

def do_foobar
  self.attribute = "value"
end
```

#### Bad (`.update_column`)

Safe because it will prevent additional callbacks from being triggered but not suggested as it can have unintended side effects.

```rb
after_save :do_foobar

private

def do_foobar
  update_column(:attribute, "value")
end
```

#### Worse (`.update`)

Can trigger subsequent callbacks infinitely.

```rb
after_save :do_foobar

private

def do_foobar
  update(attribute: "value")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  @konkurrancer.update_attributes :ratings=>'updated value'
```

Answer (score 0):

see this [after_save method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html)