# Rails stack level too deep in after_commit

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `TreatmentEvent` model. Here are the relevant parts:

```
class TreatmentEvent < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :taken #boolean
  attr_accessible :reported_taken_at #DateTime
end
```

When I set the `taken` column, I want to set `reported_taken_at` if taken is true. So I tried an `after_save` callback like so:

```
def set_reported_taken_at
  self.update_attribute(:reported_taken_at, Time.now) if taken?
end
```

I think `update_attribute` calls save, so that's causing the `stack level too deep` error. But using the `after_commit` callback is causing this to happen, too.

Is there a better way to conditionally update one column when another changes? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777172/rails-how-to-update-an-column-after-save) seems to imply you should be able to call `update_attributes` in an `after_save`.

### Edit

This also happens when using `update_attributes`:

```
 def set_reported_taken_at
   self.update_attributes(reported_taken_at: Time.now) if self.taken?
 end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a note, `stack level too deep` generally means an [`infinite loop`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_loop)

--

In your case, the issue will almost certainly be caused by:

```
after_commit :set_reported_token_at

def set_reported_taken_at
  self.update_attribute(:reported_taken_at, Time.now) if taken?
end
```

--

The problem is `after_commit` is going to try and save the `reported_taken_at` even if you've just saved a record. So you're going to go over the record *again and again and again and again...*

Often known as a [recursive loop](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Recursive+loop) - it's used a lot in native development, but for request (HTTP) based apps, it's bad as it leads to a never-ending processing of your request

---

**Fix**

Your fix should be like this:

```
#model
before_save :set_reported_token_at

def set_reported_taken_at
   self.reported_taken_at = Time.now if taken? #-> assuming you have a "taken" method 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use a before_save?  You can see if the other field value has changed and if so update this field.  That way you just have one DB call.

Comment: That still results in a `stack level too deep`. Should the method look different than above? Also, I was using `after_commit` because if it was a `create`, I couldn't use `update_attribute` because the record doesn't exist yet, right?

Comment: You were right about `before_save`, but you can't call `update_attributes`, because that'll call save. You have to assign the attribute with `=`. Add this to your answer, and I'll mark it correct. Thanks for your help.

Comment: yes, in before_save just update the attribute.  eg: model.field = value  then the save will take care of the rest

Comment: Oh, sorry, I meant add it to your answer above so your answer is complete. :)