# Rails4: How to add Computed columns in Active record

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

We have landed ourself with a column 'data' on User table that has a huge json dump in it.

Now every time we load a bunch of users we get all this data into the memory resulting into out of memory errors.

We want to be able to write some computed columns that we can use in our select statements.

```
eg:
Instead of doing this 
user.data['profile_data']['data']['image']

We would like to add a column :image and then write a query like:

Here :name and :email are actual columns on the table and :image is a computed column:
Users.where(SOME_CONDITION).select(:name,:email,:image)
```

The main use case is the index page where we display all users which basically loads data column for all users

This will avoid loading the huge data column in memory and help us load the fields we want from the data column

Whats the best way to do this in Rails4?

Updates:

- We use postgres on Heroku.

Comment: Implement this way http://stackoverflow.com/a/5777262/2767755

Comment: Are these all `:name`, `:email`, `:image` columns coming from `data` only ?

Comment: No they are not. Updated the question "Here :name and :email are actual columns on the table and :image is a computed column"

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I would move the data column to another table, but if that's not an option try the [lazy_columns](https://github.com/jorgemanrubia/lazy_columns) gem.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  lazy_load :data
end
```

Now the `data` column will be excluded during the initial load, but if you try to access the `.data` it will be retrieved from the database.

Comment: The data column will not be loaded into memory, how will that not solve it?

Comment: So we display all users in the index view. So as soon as that page is loaded all the data column would be loaded into memory. I believe using lazy_load would just delay the loading?

Answer (score 0):

Add the column `:image` using the *migration*. Then add the below code :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :extract_image

  private

  def extract_image
    self.image = self.data['profile_data']['data']['image']
    self.save
  end
end
```

[`before_save`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Callbacks/before_save): Is called before `Base.save` (regardless of whether it’s a `create` or `update` save).

Comment: I see. This would work .. but ..  I would not prefer to add new columns to the actual table because a] There are many such computed fields b] The schema of json might change and hence persisted in a schma-less column.  Thoughts ?

Comment: This is bad practice, you do not want to store calculated fields in your database.

Comment: @ricks Ok so where do you want store them? Why it is bad practice to store them to DB?

Comment: @ArupRakshit It's against Database normalization, with large datasets you a small mistake can lead to a lot of data integrity issues, if calculations are modified you need to update tables to recalculate. Plus adding more columns for calculated fields can slow down performance. Maybe its not a big deal in specific scenarios but i would still consider it bad practice.

Comment: @ricks This is a solution problem specific. Nothing will go wrong, when you have tests. For one column, I can't think of a table... complex calculation result can be cached, and keep it in sync with all the available callbacks.. Rails has **counter cache** for a reason, and if that is appreciated and helpful.. I can't go against my this answer suggestions either.

Answer (score 0):

Postgresql support two [json data type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-json.html), as described in the documentation

> There are two JSON data types: json and jsonb. They accept almost identical sets of values as input. The major practical difference is one of efficiency. The json data type stores an exact copy of the input text, which processing functions must reparse on each execution; while jsonb data is stored in a decomposed binary format that makes it slightly slower to input due to added conversion overhead, but significantly faster to process, since no reparsing is needed. jsonb also supports indexing, which can be a significant advantage.

So to solve your problem, you need to change the type of the `data` column to `jsonb` through a migration:

```
# This should use the up and down methods, because change_column 
# is not reversible     
class ChangeUsersDataColumnTypeToJsonb < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def up
      change_column :users, :data, :jsonb
   end
   def down
      change_column :users, :data, :text # or whatever datatype it was
   end
end
```

than to query the image field with you use the [functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html) that postgres provides to query the `json` data type :

```
Users.where(SOME_CONDITION).select(:name,:email,"data::json->'image' as image")
```

than you access the `image` attribute like any other attribute.

You have also to define the `:data` attribute as a [lazy loading column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28577962/676788), like , so that column do not get loaded when the user object is instantiated.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  lazy_load :data
end
```